# Oracle regex_replace is not excluding certain values

Tags: regex, select, plsql, oracle12c, regexp-replace

I have a select statement with regex_replace.

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_REPLACE(nvl(d.text_i, d.text),'[^=|]+(\||$)')),'^'||24466||'=|\|'
                                    ||24466||'=', '||'||24466||'='||'C1')  
  FROM table_infor d
   where d.tab_id = 13095;
```

I values of the column text_i and text are as below

```
text                                            text_i
26736=A||||24470=B1||||24467=||||24466=V1       (null)
26736,24470,24467,24466                         (null)
26736=A||||24470=||||24467=||||24466=V1         (null)
26736=||||24470=B1||||24467=B||||24466=V1       (null)
(null)                                           A
123                                             (null)
```

So I wanted this to print :

```
26736=||||||24470=||||||24467=|||||||24466=C1
2673,24470,24467,24466
26736=||||24470=||||24467=||||24466=C1        
26736=||||24470=||||24467=||||24466=C1 
A
123
```

But what i am getting currently is

```
26736=||||||24470=||||||24467=|||||||24466=C1
(null)
26736=||||24470=||||24467=||||24466=C1        
26736=||||24470=||||24467=||||24466=C1
```

So my regexp_replace logic for all the values that has =||||| works but for the other values it is not selecting them. I want the other values to be selected as it is.

Comment: It looks like the culprit is the first regex. Try replacing `=[^=|]+(\||$)` with `=`, that is, `REGEXP_REPLACE(nvl(d.text_i, d.text),'=[^=|]+(\||$)', '=')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'[^=|]+(\||$)'` pattern matches any one or more chars other than a `=` and `|` up to a `|` or end of string, consuming the pipe if  it is present. That means, the match will start as soon as possible. You want the matches to start only when a `=` symbol occurs.

Thus, include it in the first regex and replace with `=` to put it back:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(nvl(d.text_i, d.text),'=[^=|]+(\||$)', '=')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOml7K/1).

Comment: Hi, But i just have one doubt. SELECT (REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_REPLACE('22379=C|||||||','=[^=|]+(\||$)','=')),'^'||22379||'=|\|'
                                    ||22379||'=', '|'||22379||'='||'B'))
                                    from dual;  so here there are 7x| after C in the select statement but in the output there is only 6x|. My output is 22379=B|||||| . so something is removing one |.

Comment: @newintodev Right, if the `|` captured with `(\||$)` must stay, use `'=\1'` as replacement.